# Save current date from Lambda function but get past date in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

I write a nodejs code to run it on Lambda. The function mainly doing craw data from other sites and save to my MongoDB. I have a problem when saving `date` value. In code I have date like this which is current time.

`const date = new Date(new Date()).toISOString()`

then insert to DB

`await db.collection("videos").insertOne(dataObj) // dataObj contains date field`

I do the log on Lambda and get the correct date. But when saving to MongoDB with code below, it has been insert to DB but with wrong date value, date is in the past. I also try with `new Date()` but get same issue.

Here you can see the screenshot, the log data and inserted data.
[image]

Hope you can help me to resolve this problem.

Thank you

Comment: Please show us how do you save to your db. It looks like there is a mismatch in the way, this is not a cast problem. Did you notice that the `share_id` and `share_count` are not the same? This is not the same document before and after saving it. There are other operations in between...

Comment: I see it now. I do many query and checking DB before that. It looks like this:


1. connect to the DB
2. query for random authors `await db.collection("authors").aggregate([...]).toArray()`
3. run the loop through these authors array to get a video data for each author

[IN THE LOOP]
4. [promise] check if this author is exist on DB or not, else create new author. Return `author_id`
5. [promise] check music and return `musicId`, else create new music on DB
6. [promise] category check for assign category for video
7. [promise] hashtag check
8. [promise] get videoId

Comment: 9. [promise] from videoId, get video mp4 URL
10. [promise] transfer video URL to AWS S3, return path
11. [Promise.all] above promises
12. const videoObj = { ... data from above promises }
14. db.collection("videos").insertOne(videoObj)

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the middle there. If you share your code on the question, people will take a look and help. Maybe you can also reduce the number of queries. For example, stages 2-4 can be done in one query using `$lookup`

Comment: @nimrodserok i don't think there are operations in between, i think he just saved this video in the past and forgot about it. if you take the objectid `61bb9ad70ccf3d5f42dbc9d05` and extract the timestamp it matches the `date` saved. and the objectid contains the generated date for the document... 

@KienPham instead of `insertOne` use `updateOne` on video id, otherwise you'll have multiple instances of the same video as happened to you here

Comment: @TomSlabbaert I checked the video exist before saving it. So it isn't about `updateOne` I think.